# How to execute multiple calls and subscribes using different strategies?

Tags: angular, subscribe, switchmap

Let´s say I have something like the code below

```
this.sharedService.getvalorMensalObservable().pipe(
  switchMap(x => {
    this.valorMensal = x;
    return this.simuladorGvService.obterTaxasRecebaRapido(this.valorMensal);
    //instead of returning, I wish to make more service calls and then more than one subscribe

  })
).subscribe(response => {
  this.taxas = response;
  if (this.taxas != null) {
    this.taxasModificadas = true;
  }
});
```

I need a good example of how can I make multpiple service call, so instead of returning from one service and then execute a subscribe, I wish to make more calls and more subscribe actions. Actually, if there is more than one way, I would like to know each good way it´s possible...Promise, any Map Structure (ConcatMap?). Examples are really welcome here

Comment: That really depends on what needs to happen. Multiple calls are no problem but what needs to happen with the result of those calls?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple operators to map one observable to another. Each has their unique use case. It all depends how the observables are co-dependent on each other. I'd recommend you to see [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/) to know the difference between common mapping strategies.

In regards to the code you posted, you could continue piping operators for multiple calls.

```js
this.sharedService.getvalorMensalObservable().pipe(
  switchMap(x => {
    this.valorMensal = x;
    return this.simuladorGvService.obterTaxasRecebaRapido(this.valorMensal);
  }),
  switchMap(x => this.otherService.transformData(x)),
  switchMap(x => this.someotherService.transformData(x)),
  .
  .
).subscribe(response => {
  this.taxas = response;
  if (this.taxas != null) {
    this.taxasModificadas = true;
  }
});
```